# What happens when KVM virtual machines try to use the same core of a processor?

Tags: cpu, virtualization, linux-kvm

I have many virtual machines hosted with KVM on a single server. The problem(?) is there are now more machines then cores of the processor. From what I found I cannot use more RAM then I have but can I have more machines then cores?

What happens when two guests have to use the same core? Will one of them wait for free core (and completely freeze for some time longer then 1 second) or will they simply use the same core and host will switch between them constantly (simply putting more load on the core). Could this switching be a problem for guest machine?

I'm asking because weird things happens on one of Windows guests (e.g. searching is not working and some services die) -- not sure if that is related. Linux guests seem fine, but I do have to restart them from time to time.

Comment: _"Linux guests seem fine, but I do have to restart them from time to time."_ – Why do you restart them if they work fine? And if they

Comment: By "seem fine" I mean there are no major problems (like on Windows machine). But they do get slow with time. Might be unrelated to virtualization though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have more VMs than cores. The hypervisor's job is to divide the CPU usage, just like a regular kernel would schedule multiple processes. In fact, with KVM the virtual machines are scheduled pretty much *exactly* like regular processes by the same Linux host kernel.

(Remember that virtualization also works on single-core systems, which means the hypervisor, the host, and the guest must run on the same core. Therefore multiple guests can share a core as well. That's the whole point of virtualization, after all.)